# C# - Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I am receiving the error above when trying to run this statement:

```
internal static void getCommand(string command, string arg)
{
    command == "debug";
}
```

Comment: You're trying to make a comparison between two values, but do nothing with the result of that comparison.  Even if it compiled, it would literally accomplish nothing.  What do you *expect* this code to do?

Comment: I just wrote the string, I haven't even gotten to writing is use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing a *boolean statement*, not a *declaration statement* there.

```
// This results in True or False.
command == "debug";

// This assigns the value of command to 'debug'
command = "debug";
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my issue!

Comment: No problem, all the down-votes you received are unfortunate. Questions are two easily dismissed here for newbies. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Should be either of the following depending on what you are trying to achieve:

```
internal static void getCommand(string command, string arg)
{
    // comparison
    if (command == "debug")
    {
      // do something
    } 
}
```

OR

```
internal static void getCommand(string command, string arg)
{
    //assignment
    command = "debug";
}
```

Your code is currently doing neither. Not sure what your code needs to do but one of these should be it..